# Workaround to make IEnumerator somehow return value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server, timestamp

In my Unity game you can place various objects on the surface of the terrain and I need to save the timestamp in a file when new object is placed. I have the saving system working and with some help I was able to get timestamp from the server. It seems you must use IEnumerator in order to get data from server but this created a new problem for me. Since IEnumerator is not a function it can't simply return anything. And since it can't return anything I need a workaround to pass the timestamp from the IEnumerator back to the place it was asked for. How I planned I would be able to get the timestamp:

```
 int _timestamp = ServerTime.Get();
```

So I could easily store it like

```
gameObject.GetComponent<_DrillStats>().timestamp = _timestamp;
gameObject.GetComponent<_OtherStats>().timestamp = _timestamp;
gameObject.GetComponent<_EvenMoreStats>().timestamp = _timestamp;
```

Here is the full code for receiving the timestamp:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class ServerTime : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static ServerTime localInstance;
    public static ServerTime time { get { return localInstance; } }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (localInstance != null && localInstance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            localInstance = this;
        }
    }

    public static void Get()
    {
        if (time == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Script not attached to anything");
            GameObject obj = new GameObject("TimeHolder");
            localInstance = obj.AddComponent<ServerTime>();
            Debug.Log("Automatically Attached Script to a GameObject");
        }

        time.StartCoroutine(time.ServerRequest());
    }

    IEnumerator ServerRequest()
    {
        WWW www = new WWW("http://www.businesssecret.com/something/servertime.php");

        yield return www;

        if (www.error == null) 
        {
            int _timestamp = int.Parse (www.text);

            // somehow return _timestamp
            Debug.Log (_timestamp);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError ("Oops, something went wrong while trying to receive data from the server, exiting with the following ERROR: " + www.error);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30270515/3785314).  The answer with the `Action` parameter is what you are looking for.

Comment: Changed to: 
`time.StartCoroutine (time.ServerRequest (www, (status) => {
    print (status.ToString ());
}));`

and

`IEnumerator ServerRequest(WWW www, Action<int> callback)
 {
  yield return www;

  if (www.error == null) 
  {
   int _timestamp = int.Parse (www.text);

   callback (_timestamp);
  }
  else
  {
   Debug.LogError ("Oops, something went wrong while trying to receive data from the server, exiting with the following ERROR: " + www.error);
  }

 }`

But I still don't understand how I can pass the given timestamp back to the other script that required it.

Comment: I don't know how to format above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I meant in the comment section:

```
public static void Get(Action<int> callback)
{
    if (time == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Script not attached to anything");
        GameObject obj = new GameObject("TimeHolder");
        localInstance = obj.AddComponent<ServerTime>();
        Debug.Log("Automatically Attached Script to a GameObject");
    }

    time.StartCoroutine(time.ServerRequest(callback));
}

IEnumerator ServerRequest(Action<int> callback)
{
    WWW www = new WWW("http://www.businesssecret.com/something/servertime.php");

    yield return www;

    if (www.error == null)
    {
        int _timestamp = int.Parse(www.text);

        // somehow return _timestamp
        callback(_timestamp);

        Debug.Log(_timestamp);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Oops, something went wrong while trying to receive data from the server, exiting with the following ERROR: " + www.error);
    }
}
```

I made both function take `Action<int>` as parameter.

**USGAE**:

Replace `ServerTime.Get();` with:

```
ServerTime.Get((myTimeStamp) =>
{
    Debug.Log("Time Stamp is: " + myTimeStamp);

    gameObject.GetComponent<_DrillStats>().timestamp = myTimeStamp;
    gameObject.GetComponent<_OtherStats>().timestamp = myTimeStamp;
    gameObject.GetComponent<_EvenMoreStats>().timestamp = myTimeStamp;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the timestamp to a field, and access it after coroutine is completed.

You can use a while loop with a bool flag to wait for coroutine to finish.

Comment: Do you mean adding while loop after the `time.StartCoroutine(time.ServerRequest());`
wouldn't that cause a freeze in the game while Coroutine is running?