# How to create Wait/Delay/Pause

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try this:

```
void RUN()
{
    Debug.Log("Before Corutine");
    StartCoroutine(Test());
    Debug.Log("After Corutine");
}


IEnumerator Test()
{
    Debug.Log("Before Wait");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    Debug.Log("After Wait");
}
```

And I get:

Before Corutine
Before Wait
After Corutine
*(after 5 seconds)*
After Wait

My dream is get:

Before Corutine
Before Wait
*(wait 5 seconds)*
After Wait
After Corutine

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267537/unity-need-to-return-value-only-after-coroutine-finishes

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm They are not related. OP doesn't want to return a value. Although this is a duplicate of many *other* questions. Just can't find them anymore.

Comment: Well, yes, he doesn't need to return data. But that answer clearly explains how to do a synchronous coroutine, which is what the OP needs. Answer is still the same (see the answer servy provided, same thing).

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to make `RUN` a coroutine (adjusting all calls to it accordingly), and you'll need to `yield` the result of `StartCoroutine`.

**EDIT**:

```
IEnumerator RUN()
{
    Debug.Log("Before Corutine");
    yield return StartCoroutine(Test());
    Debug.Log("After Corutine");
}


IEnumerator Test()
{
    Debug.Log("Before Wait");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    Debug.Log("After Wait");
}
```

Wherever you call `RUN()`, you must now call with `StartCoroutine(RUN());`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I showed just prototype. 
In real Test() have a get a few variables and return a variable and .. it is a recursion proc :( 
That is why I dont want to create RUN() as coroutine :(
I presents a results calculated by RUN() using Test() and it is to fast. Thats why I'd like to make a small delay inside Test().

Comment: @user3246203 That doesn't change the answer.  As much as you might not want to make it a coroutine, that is the solution.  You can still recursively call a coroutine.

Comment: @user3246203 I think you need to read up on how asynchronous programming works lol. If you don't want RUN to be IEnumerator, perhaps you can open a thread? Haven't used Unity in a while, but pretty sure you could just spin off a new async thread and not have the method itself be IEnumerator.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm My understanding of unity (which, granted, isn't too deep) is that that would be very bad practice for something like this as that would be, from a performance standpoint, unacceptably slow and high in resource consumption in almost all situations.  That's the whole reason for having the coroutine system in the first place; it's a *much* more lightweight way of supporting asynchronous operations than using threads merely to create asynchrony.

Comment: Well because he said he didn't want to use an IEnumerator as a datatype for his method. I simply said there ARE ways around that. Regardless if they *might* be a performance drop, it's still a viable option.

Comment: In .NET you can surely have a non-async method, and open an async thread to perform a request. So that's why i suggested it. It's possible, but apparently in Unity it's not to be used. But still an option.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm Like I said, the performance cost of using a thread to do something like that in a context like this is almost certainly unacceptable.  Using another method of asynchrony that didn't use threads would be non-idiomatic, and likely more difficult than it would need to be, but could potentially work.  Using new threads is almost certainly simply not going to be a practical option, and again, is setting up the person for tons of problems down the line, so suggesting that they do so is extremely disingenuous.

Comment: I'm not at really any concern as to if something is disingenuous, he asked a question and I answered it. Really not sure why we're still talking about this. I clearly mentioned you were right. However, I am right in that it IS an option. However disingenuousit is. It still would work. Let's move on now.

Comment: Also, people use threading in Unity. Really not sure what you're on about http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/357033/unity3d-and-c-coroutines-vs-threading.html

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm I didn't say you should *never* use threads in unity, but rather than *this is not an appropriate situation in which to use them*, and that try to do so in this context would almost certainly not actually be an option.  You say it would work, it almost certainly would not, in a practical sense, work.  That you simply don't care that you're taking a harmful action, even knowing that it's a harmful action, says a lot about you.

Comment: It would most definitely work. Lol, but like I said let's drop this. I don't see it as harmful. That's your opinion.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm But it wouldn't, that's the point.  It's like telling someone who's having car trouble on a cross country trip to just walk everywhere.  Yes, it's technically possible to walk places; it's even possible to walk cross country, but for that person, in context, it's simply *not going to work* as a solution to their problem; they need their car fixes (or perhaps a replacement car).  If this person tries to use threads for stuff like this instead of coroutines then their game is going to be utterly unplayable.

Comment: Like I said, that's your opinion. Have you tried? No, you're just going off of your opinion. I find it odd someone who's not too familiar with Unity, is talking like they are. `My understanding of unity (which, granted, isn't too deep)...` Like I've said about 5 times now. Let's drop this and move on. It's not helping the OP at all and really is inappropriate.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm I'm rather intimately familiar with threading and various asynchronous systems.  I also know enough of the basics of unity to know the basic model used, and why it's used.  I certainly do know that trying to use threads to solve problems like this in a gaming context *is* going to cause *major* performance problems.  That's not just some opinion, I can certainly say that much from experience.  Not pointing out how extremely harmful your advice is and just letting you advocate harmful choices would be "not helping the OP".